# Calculate $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \phi_{\frac{S_n}{n}}(t)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

They give me $X_1, X_2, X_3, ...$ random variables that are independent and with the same distribution and they ask me to calculate $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \phi_{\frac{S_n}{n}}(t)$.

**Obs:** $S_n = X_1 + ... X_n$ and $E(X_i) = \mu$.

Well my first idea is to see what is $\phi_{\frac{S_n}{n}}(t)$:

$\phi_{\frac{S_n}{n}}(t) = \phi_{S_n}(\frac{t}{n}) = (\phi_{X_1}(\frac{t}{n}))^n $

$\phi_{X_1}(\frac{t}{n}) = E(e^{\frac{itX}{n}}) = \int_{\Omega}e^{\frac{itX}{n}}dP = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{\frac{itx}{n}}f(x)dx$

But from here I don't know how can I continue.

Comment: What is $\phi$ in this context?

Comment: The characteristic function of a random variable

Comment: In that case, I don't think it can be simplified any more without knowing the distribution of $X_i$

Comment: But the solution says that $lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \phi_{\frac{S_n}{n}}(t) \longrightarrow \phi_{\mu}(t) = e^{\mu i t}$

Comment: Oh my bad, I didn't see $\lim_{n \to \infty}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the strong law of large numbers you get $$\frac{S_n}{n} \to \mu \quad a.s $$ but this implies $$ \phi_\frac{S_n}{n} \to \phi_\mu $$ by dominated convergence theorem which lead to the wanted result

Comment: Okey, so the point that I was omitting is use the dominated convergence theorem